# Bing Maps, can I use aerial imagery to edit my data like Waze?

Tags: bing-maps, gis, waze

I want to create a web interface where I can adjust my own "street" data to match aerial images of streets so that it is more accurate. I will have someone who is on the street, will see that it is inaccurately represented on my map and then they will go to the web interface to update it.

I understand that Waze used Bing aerial tiles to do this in their map editor (https://www.waze.com/editor/) before they were acquired by Google. Is this sort of function still available from Bing?

My worry is that maps like Google or OpenStreetMaps do not allow for you to "trace" their aerial tiles. Although this is a question of legality in the case of Bing, I am more interested in suggestions for mapping services that would allow me to integrate this functionality into my web interface.

Note: I am not taking answers here as legal advice. I understand that I am legally liable for whatever I chose to do, I am just looking for suggestions on an aerial map I could use for my project.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the base map data is. Bing Maps already provides OpenStreetMaps with aerial imagery which can be used to trace roads in their editor tool. I can't see OpenStreetMaps disabling this any time soon as long as Bing continues to provide them with access to the aerial imagery.

Send me an email at richbrun at microsoft.com and we can discuss in more detail.